# Intuition behind Lagrange multiplier

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I noticed that all attempts of showcasing the intuition behind Lagrange's multipliers basically resort to the following example (taken from Wikipedia):
[image]

The reason why such examples make sense is that the level curves of the f function are either only decreasing (d1 < d2 < d3) or only increasing (d1 > d2 > d3) concentrically, so it's obvious that the most centric level curve touching the constraint curve is the minimum/maximum that we are looking for.

But in real life examples, I imagine we can have a function f whose level curves might look like this (they don't decrease/increase in an orderly fashion):

[image]

In the above example that I thought of, the maximization of f (subject to the g constraint) would not be the blue point (where the constraint curve is tangent to a level curve of f), but the two green points.

I haven't seen this kind of level arrangement in any tutorial/lecture/course and it just seems to me that every demonstration conveniently picks the most favorable scenario for presenting the intuition. I must be wrong somewhere but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous, this kind of arrangement can't happen.  To see this, consider a continuous path going from the the $f=1$ curve to the $f=4$ curve.  Let $(x(t), y(t))$ denote a (continuous) paramaterization of such a path with, say $(x(0), y(0))$ a point on the $f=1$ curve and $(x(1), y(1))$ a point on the $f=4$ curve.

Then we get a single variable continuous function by mapping $t$ to $f(x(t),y(t))$.  If we plug in $t=0$, we get $f(x(0), y(0)) = 1$ and likewise, if we plug in $t=1$, we get $f(x(1), y(1)) = 4$.  By the intermediate value theorem, there is some $t$ we can plug in for which $f(x(t),y(t)) = 3$.

In terms of your picture, what this says is that any continuous curve which starts at the $f=1$ curve and ends at the $f=4$ curve must pass through the $f=3$ curve.  If you think about this, you should be able to convince yourself that this forces the curves $f=1$, $f=3$, and $f=4$ to be concentric, as it is in the pictures you typically see.

**Edit**:  Let me try to address it a little differently so that you can see why the connectedness of the $f=3$ curve is irrelevant.  The issue is that no one is claiming that a place where $f$ and $g$ are tangent is a max or min of $f$.  Rather, the claim is the the only hope of finding a max or min of $f$ is at a point where $f$ and $g$ are tangent (for reasonbly smooth $f$ and $g$), or where $f$ already has a max or min.

Here is the argument (which is essentially what amd wrote in his/her answer) with a bit more hand waving.)  Suppose $(x_0,y_0)$ is a point along the curve $g(x,y) = c$ for which $f(x_0,y_0)$ is a maximum.  (I'll use notation for the value $d = f(x_0,y_0)$.)

The question is: how are $f$ and $g$ related at $(x_0,y_0)$?

Well, zoom in incredibly close to $(x_0,y_0)$.  At this resolution, all you see is a very small part of the curve $g(x,y) = c$ and a very small portion of one connected piece of the curve $f = d$.  The point is that while the curve $f=d$ may have infinitely many components, we are zooming in so far as to only see the a part of the one containing $(x_0,y_0)$.

Because we are zoomed in very close, for intuition purposes, we may as well replace $g$ and $f$ by their tangent lines.  If these tangent lines are different, then the line $g = c$ passes from one side of the line $f = d$ to the other.  If $f$ does *not* have a local min/max at $(x,y)$, then the values must be higher on one side of the $f$-line and lower on other.  Since the line $g = c$ crosses the line $f = d$, by using points on one side or the other of the $f$-line, we can find points on $g=c$ which make $f$ even bigger than $d$.  This is a problem: $d$ was supposed to be the maximum value!

So something had to go wrong.  We have already identified both problems.  First, maybe the tangent line to $f$ was equal to the tangent line to $g$.  Then the $g$ line doesn't cross the $f$ line.  Second, if $f$ has a local max at $(x,y)$ then points on $g(x,y)  =c$ don't increase the size of $f$ as the $g$ line crosses the $f$ line.  (Another thing that could go wrong:  maybe $f$ just doesn't have a maximum subject to the constraint.  This issue actually can't arise if the graph of $g = c$ doesn't go off to infinity in some direction.)

Comment: If $f$ is discontinuous, I know of no general methods of maximizing it subject to a constraint.  Even worse, generally there should be no reason that a maximum even exists for a discontinuous $f$.  But perhaps for certain kinds of discontinuities, something is known.

Comment: I understand from your reasoning why there must also be a level curve of f=3 between the f=1 and f=4 curves, but why can't there be two f=3 level curves? If, for example, the graph of f would look like a ripple effect on a water surface, then multiple concentric level curves of the same value would be possible, right?

Comment: Yes, that can definitely happen.  For example, $f(x,y) = \sin( \sqrt{x^2 + y^2})$ looks like that - there are infinitely many connected level curves corresponding to $f = 1$.

Comment: I've tried to address your concern about $f=3$ having multiple components.  Let me know if I can further clarify!

Comment: Thank you for your step-by-step explanation, it helped clear up my confusion!

Answer (score 20):

For my part, I don’t find that way of explaining the Lagrange multiplier method particularly enlightening. Instead, I like to think of it in terms of directional derivatives. Suppose we have $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ and wish to find the critical points of $f$ restricted to the curve $\gamma$. If we “straighten out” $\gamma$, this becomes the familiar problem of finding the critical points of a single-variable function, which occur where its derivative vanishes. The analog of this condition in the original, non-straightened setting is that the directional derivative of $f$ in a direction tangent to $\gamma$ vanishes: loosely, $\nabla f\cdot \gamma'=0$. Now, the gradient of a function is normal to its level curves, so if $\gamma$ is given as the level curve of a function $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$, then this condition is equivalent to the two gradients being parallel, i.e., $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$. This idea generalizes to higher dimensions: we have instead a level (hyper)surface of $g$ and want the derivative of $f$ in *every* direction tangent to $g$ to vanish, which is equivalent to the gradients of the two functions being parallel. For suitably well-behaved functions $g$, the above conceptual “flattening out” of the hypersurface is justified in a neighborhood of a point by the Implicit Function theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your original interpretation! It contributed to my better understanding of the phenomenon, in correlation with Jason DeVito's answer.

Comment: what do you mean when you say straighten out?

Comment: The answer is in the following 30 seconds or so in the following video https://youtu.be/5A39Ht9Wcu0?t=153

Answer (score 6):

I am imagining your proposed $f(x, y)$ to look like ripples on a pond, with the $f=4$ contour being a wave crest ring, and the $f=1$ contour being a wave trough ring.

The green points are *unconditional* local maxima for $f$. That is, they are optima even if we don't enforce $g=c$. At those points, the gradient of $f$ is the zero vector. The equation $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ will still hold for $\lambda = 0 $, so your example hasn't broken anything. All that happens is that we lose the geometric statement "gradients are parallel" because *the zero vector has no direction.* This always occurs when an unconditional optima of $f$ *happens* to perfectly touch $g$.

The $f=3$ contour is more interesting, because I have not imagined it to necessarily be a crest or trough. It could just be part of a swell. Regardless, the blue point has to be listed as a candidate in the Lagrange multiplier method. The method says that all constrained optima will satisfy $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ but it doesn't say that non-optima can't. It is just a *necessary* condition.

Anyway, I find the following to be a convincing argument that Lagrange multipliers work. It comes from Wikipedia:

> The method of Lagrange multipliers relies on the intuition that at a maximum, $f(x, y)$ cannot be increasing in the direction of any neighboring point where $g = c$. If it were, we could walk along $g = c$ to get higher, meaning that the starting point wasn't actually the maximum.

(...i.e. if the gradient of $f$ had any component along $g=c$, it would be giving us a direction to walk, so optima must have $\nabla f$ orthogonal to $g=c$, or equivalently parallel to $\nabla g$).

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the constraint curve being tangent to a level curve is necessary but not sufficient for a constrained optima, it was a very useful insight. The comments on the unconditional maxima helped as well!

Comment: Glad I could help :)